# Can we index and search with different languages in the same Solr index?

Tags: solr, multilingual

I have data coming from an external system (in CSV form).
The data contains fields like :

```
id - french_title - english_title - french_desc - english_desc etc...
```

I know I can use multiple cores but is there a way to index and search this with just one core?

For example, can I tell Solr to use a French Analyzer on french_title and french_desc and an English analyzer on english_title and english_desc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work since Solr lets you configure the analyzer to use [on a per-field basis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Specifying_an_Analyzer_in_the_schema).